# Swing: Ignore text box focus lost event when specific button clicked

Tags: java, swing, jtextcomponent, documentlistener, focuslistener

I have a swing textbox that contains a value which is validated on focuslost event.
The form has many other controls, including a cancel button.
I want validation to be skipped in case focus has been lost due to clicking of cancel button.
How can this be done?

Comment: You can always check the OppositeComponent of the FocusEvent, but this is usually not really maintainable.

Comment: @Guillaume : Your suggestion worked for me. Hacky and unmaintainable, but does the trick. If you add it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to remove the code which performs validation on `focusLost` and either implement your validation in a `DocumentListener`, or opt for a `JFormattedTextField` which has built-in validation.

Also from a user perspective I prefer on-the-fly validation instead of on focus-lost. When I start typing, it is nice to see when your input becomes incorrect. Further, you could opt to disable the OK button while there is invalid input, and only leave the cancel button enabled. This of course requires that your validation does not pop-up messages but just adds an indication in/next to the input fields

Comment: Some validations can be costly when done on keypress. Otherwise, valuable suggestions.